# Circular regression- R-Squared Value

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

Just like we have $R^2$ in linear regression, How do I find out the 'goodness of fit' of a circle to a given data?

Is it wrong to use the $R^2$ formula from linear regression,
$R^2 \equiv 1 - \frac{SS_{res}}{SS_{tot}}$ for circular regression? If so, why?

[Here](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/574697/Sample_data.txt)(or [here](http://pastebin.com/snm7ZbmD)) is a sample data for which I would like to find out $R^2$ value with respect to a unit circle.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "how close is the given data to the circumference of a unit circle"?

Comment: Do you have data in polar coordinate? Are your data points uniformly spaced over the angular axis?

Comment: @gung : I meant how good the data approximates the unit circle.

Comment: @Memming : No. I have data in Cartesian coordinate and they are not uniformly spaced.

Comment: See this blog post by Rick Wicklin for an example of estimating the center and radius, http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2015/06/08/fit-circle.html

Comment: It could be helpful if you can post an example dataset.

Comment: @Memming: I have added a sample dataset. And also edited the question in a more general way.

Comment: Thanks. That helps. What do you mean by circular regression? As long as you define your error correctly, R^2 makes sense.